# How to get bitmap in imageView OR picasso

Tags: java, bitmap, imageview, picasso

Why does **null** return?

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

In addition, when I use picasso, it does not goto the **onBitmapLoaded** method

```
 Picasso.get().load("url").into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
         //Does not go to this method  
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
              //Coming this method
        }
    });
```

what's the problem ? Why can't I get a bitmap from imageView?
Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I used **background** for imageView
must be used **src**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img"/>

ImageVew imageView = findViewById(R.id.activityGetMainColor_img);
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Comment: it would be better if you could add some examples or code in your answer.